# How do i extract json data in yii2 applaication

Tags: php, json, yii2

i have a data in this form below

```
var bet_info = [{"country":"ENG ","league":"Premier League 
(GB)","home_team":"Chelsea","away_team":"Tottenham","opt":"W1 ","odds":1.2,"startDate":1605456000}, 
{"country":"ENG ","league":"Premier League (GB)","home_team":"Everton","away_team":"Fulham","opt":"X 
","odds":3.4,"startDate":1605549600}]
```

and i send it to the server using ajax

```
         $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {bet_info:bet_info},
            success: function (data) {  
                $("#smallModal").hide();
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) {
             // handle error
                   $("#smallModal").hide();
                    alert('server error occur. try again later');
                    console.log(errMsg);
            }
        });
```

and in my controller i have the below

```
     if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
         $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

         $myArray = json_decode($data['bet_info'], true);
         echo $myArray[0]['home_team'];

         /*also try to decode it as object*/
         $myArray = json_decode($data['bet_info'];
         echo $myArray[0]->home_team;

         /*also try to loop through it as an array*/
          foreach($data['bet_info'] as $betInfo){
            $a[] = $betInfo['home_team'];
         }

         return $a;

     }else{
         throw new ForbiddenHttpException(\Yii::t('app','You\'re not allowed to access this page').'.');
     }
```

None of the above try is working for me, sometime i get parseError
how can get the data as array or object to i can loop through it to save it to database
Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: You probably should use `return $this->asJson($a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the change code on controller:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $myArray = $data["bet_info"];

        echo $myArray[0]['home_team'];

        /*also try to decode it as object*/
        $myArray = $data['bet_info'];
        echo $myArray[0]['home_team'];

        /*also try to loop through it as an array*/
        foreach($data['bet_info'] as $betInfo){
            $a[] = $betInfo['home_team'];
        }

        return json_encode($a);

    }else{
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException(\Yii::t('app','You\'re not allowed to access this page').'.');
    }
```

Your post data is not json string, it is an array. So we get all request data as normal

Comment: I tried this but it didn't solve the problem, i get PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Illegal string offset 'home_team'' error when i try to access the request as normal data and loop through it or print the array using the key

Comment: I have checked on loop and can print home_team. Can you double check my code above and your code.

Comment: I check the code it's same with yours but still having same error, so i want to know how i can make my ajax send the data in json format rather than normal data, since what i got from post data is not a json string, how can i make it a json string

Comment: I finally figure out the problem, i just need to parse the json string using JSON.parse() in my js code before sending it to the server and then i can access it as normal data like you explained in your answer